# Papers on Algorithms in Robotics

Tags: navigation, algorithm, theory, coverage

I'm a CS student and I need to give a 30-minute lecture about 1-2 papers describing 1-2 algorithms for any of the main problems in Robotics (navigation, coverage, patrolling, etc.).

I have no background in Robotics specifically, but I did take classes such as Algorithms and AI (including some basic AI algorithms such as [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), [IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search), [UCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Practical_optimizations_and_infinite_graphs), and subjects such as [decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning), [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory), etc.).
The difference between simply describing one of the above is that I need the paper to refer to actual physical robots and their algorithms, with real problems in the physical world, as opposed to AI "agents" with more theoretical algorithms.

I am required to lecture on 1-2 academic papers, published from 2012 onward, with a "respectable" amount of citations. Any suggestions of such papers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question and OP hasn't shown any effort, because it's a literature request, and because there's no specific question based on a problem OP actually faces. The question is, "I need 2 papers on robots," with no other direction. Is it a request for papers on unmanned deep sea navigation or on vending machines?

Comment: That said, if *I* were OP, I'd use the university library's database to search papers on algorithms I were interested in, then see who cited *those* papers. Then I could find papers that reference algorithms I was interested in.

Comment: @Chuck It's not a classic "do my homework" question. I have searched Google Scholar with basic keywords, however, as I mentioned, I do not have **any** experience or even basic knowledge in this field. That is why I'm asking the community for a few suggestions of papers to start me off. I can search and read through tens of papers, eventually arriving at a few good ones, or I can ask for some advice and suggestions from people who know more about this than I.

Comment: If you haven't been taught about applied robotics applications, nobody else in your class has, either. So, you've got the same problem everyone else does - a *research* problem. As I said above, you provide no topics you're interested in, so it's hard for anyone here to give any relevant feedback. As I also said, my advice would be to use your *university library* to search databases like IEEE Xplore, look for algorithms you're interested in, then see who cited them. Search *quality journals* and get quality papers.

Comment: @Chuck Thanks, I'll definitely try that out.

Comment: @Cauthon If you really know nothing, then academic papers might be a bit dry and too deep. There are occasionally survey papers that are helpful, but at this stage, you'd be better off going to higher-level publications. The Journal of Field Robotics and the IEEE Robotics and Automation Magazine are good options for higher-level, but still technical, discussions of robotics. Your librarian can help you find recent articles in these periodicals.

Comment: @JoshVanderHook thanks, I eventually found two interesting ones, one from the IEEE and another from ACM symposium.

Answer (score 1):

You might like the algorithms run on PR-2 robot. Two papers I can think of are "A single planner for a composite task of approaching, opening and navigating through non-spring and spring-loaded doors" and "Motion planning for smooth pickup of moving objects". Both can be found on IEEE Xplore.